# Docusign | E-Signatures | Docusign Sandbox | Default signatures are digital signatures or just an image?

Tags: docusignapi

I've a use-case to integrate e-signature with an existing application of some confidential customer.

While working with the sandbox, here is how i'm sending the envelope for remote signing.

[image]

Query is:  Are these default signature "digital signatures" i.e. Whether PKI certificates are involved in it ?

Comment: If the answer helped steer you in the right direction, please be sure to upvote and accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short version - No. By default, you are creating an electronic signature.

Long version (excerpted from a [support article](https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/Electronic-and-Digital-Signatures) on this very topic)

An electronic signature, or eSignature, is the broad umbrella category under which all electronic signatures fall. Digital signatures are a specific signature technology implementation of electronic signature.

Organizations typically refer to eSignature as the process a person goes through to demonstrate their intent during an electronic transaction whereas a digital signature refers to the encryption technology containing critical metadata pertaining to the e-signature. The eSignature is the legally binding record while the digital signature is the underlying technology that helps verify the authenticity of the transaction.

DocuSign Standards-Based Signatures is a core feature of DocuSign’s platform that enables customers to enjoy the full range of signature capabilities while staying compliant with local and industry e-signature standards. In the EU, there are three key signatures in the DocuSign Standards-Based Signature portfolio, Express Signature, EU Advanced Signature, and EU Qualified Signature.

Should you want to implement digital signatures with DocuSign, you would want to enable the Standards-Based Signatures feature. Assuming you are a developer using our eSignature API, contact support to have this feature turned on within your demo sandbox account.

[More specific info on SBS here](https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/Standards-Based-Signatures-Data-Sheet.pdf).

Comment: Thanks @Matthew for the clarification. Yes, I need SBS in my sandbox. Can you guide me how(via which channel) to contact the support to enable that ?

Comment: Sure thing. Go ahead and email your request to apihelp@docusign.com